# How can I make a square with a specified circumference and add margin?

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to make a square path of a specified length:

I made a function - and if I put 20 then I get a 6x6 matrix.

How can I add a margin of 0's of eg. 3 fields thickness?

like this

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

```py
def square(length): return [
    [1 for _ in range(length//4+1)]
    for _ in range(length//4+1)
]

for x in square(24):
    print(x)
```

Comment: This would be easier in `numpy`.  Will you be doing computation with this grid?

Comment: Can you explain `How can I add a margin of 0's of eg. 3 fields thickness?` ? I could not understand what you need.

Comment: yes I added an example.

Comment: numpy would be ok, the matrix will be used for drawing a map in a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare a line pattern of 0s and 1s then build a 2D matrix by intersecting them.

```
def square(size,margin=3):
    p = [0]*margin + [1]*(size-2*margin) + [0]*margin
    return [[r*c for r in p] for c in p]

for row in square(20):print(*row)

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  One caution here is that, because of the way I duplicated the zero rows, those are all the same list.  If you modify one of the zero rows, it will modify all of them.

```
def square(length): 
    zeros = [0]*(length//4+7)
    sq = [zeros] * 3
    sq.extend( [
        ([0,0,0] + [1 for _ in range(length//4+1)] + [0,0,0] )
        for _ in range(length//4+1)
    ])
    sq.extend( [zeros]*3 )
    return sq

for x in square(24):
    print(x)
```

Here's a numpy method.

```
import numpy as np
def square(length): 
    c = length//4+1
    sq = np.zeros((c+6,c+6)).astype(int)
    sq[3:c+3,3:c+3] = np.ones((c,c))
    return sq

print( square(24) )
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Roberts

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to build it as a flat string, then use `textwrap` to style the output into the right number of lines:

```
import textwrap

# The number of 1's in a row/column
count = 6
# The number of 0's to pad with
margin = 3
# The total 'size' of a row/column
size = margin + count + margin

pad_rows = "0" * size * margin
core = (("0" * margin) + ("1" * count) + ("0" * margin)) * count
print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(pad_rows + core + pad_rows, size)))
```